# What is the maximum player level to get a prestige?

Tags: awesomenauts

What's the max level in the steam version of the game (patch 2.5 I believe)? I know that the answer should be easily googleable, but I only found the number "122", which is incorrect at the moment (I am at 129 or 130 right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be 134.

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/204300/discussions/0/540744935074265727/)

> It's 134, just checked. Max level will always be the final upgrade of the latest character.

Comment: Currently, yes. Witch each new Awesomenaut it gets (6 levels?) higher.

Answer (score 4):

The max level depends on the number of Awesomenauts available. Currently, [the max level is 138, with the patch 2.8](http://steamcommunity.com/app/204300/discussions/0/627456486407633149/), then 144 with the patch 2.9. If a new Awesomenauts is released in a future patch/version, the level will increase by 7 or 8, to unlock new upgrades for this Awesomenauts (plus some empty levels, sometimes).

By accessing to the max level, you can [unlock a level of prestige](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Prestige).

---

With release of Awesomenauts 3.5, [the level requirement](https://steamcommunity.com/app/204300/discussions/0/135511757694397359/#c135511757694786641) was 192.